# Merging Queries with no common keys

Tags: ms-access, merge

I'm kinda new to Access and would like some advice on how to merge two queries together.

The structure of the queries is identical.

The column headings are: Test Object,Test Case,Status,Tester 1,Tester 2,Tester 3 and Defect Number

Ideally I only want to keep Test Object, Test Case, Status and Defect Number. Additionally is there a way to merge the Test Object and Test Case into a single field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RE: "merging" queries together**

A `UNION` query is a type of query that combines two (sub-)queries into one result set, e.g.,

```
SELECT [Test Object], [Test Case], [Status], [Defect Number] FROM YourQuery1
UNION
SELECT [Test Object], [Test Case], [Status], [Defect Number] FROM YourQuery2
```

**RE: combining two columns**

You can do that in an Access query by using the ampersand (`&`) operator to concatenate:

```
SELECT [Test Object] & ", " & [Test Case] AS Object_Case, ...
```